# Update title position when all elements have the same title (Webkit browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

I have a couple of elements which all have the same title attribute. When you hover a element the title shows as expected.

But when I move the mouse really fast to the next element, the title doesn't update its position but stays over the first element.

The problem is only presence in webkit browsers like chrome and safari

See this fiddle for a example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EjnEb/9/

```
<li class="" id="tab1" title="Drag and drop">managers</li>
<li class="" id="tab2" title="Drag and drop">Standings</li>
```

Comment: It's browser (and maybe OS) dependent, I experience the same thing, but its fine, I wouldn't worry about this at all. It isn't something you can fix. You could always use a tooltip plugin.

Comment: unfortunately the client does :/ In my case the elements are much bigger than the list entries in the example

Comment: Send your client a link to this question. Or use a tooltip plugin and customize the css to make it look just like Windows XP or something. I feel your frustration.